# What caused Stripe's BAD_REQUEST in testing mode: "You cannot use a live bank account number when making transfers or debits in test mode"?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

When I send request to update an existing custom account I get this message: `You cannot use a live bank account number when making transfers or debits in test mode` along with 400 BAD_REQUEST:

```
"error" => [
      "type" => "invalid_request_error"
      "message" => "You cannot use a live bank account number when making transfers or debits in test mode"
      "param" => "external_account[account_number]"
    ]
```

Inspecting the data I send to Stripe I discovered that this error occurs only when there is this data in the request body:

```
"external_account" => array:6 [
    "object" => "bank_account"
    "account_number" => "1212121212"
    "country" => "BE"
    "currency" => "EUR"
    "account_holder_name" => "NAME LASTNAME"
    "account_holder_type" => "company"
  ]
```

I tried to use different fake bank account numbers, but it did not help. The only way to successfully update data is to avoid this `external_account` data at all.

I wonder if there is something I can do to make Stripe accept it? Since this error only appears during functional tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In test mode Stripe assumes that any number that isn't explicitly one of [their test numbers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#account-numbers) is a potentially real account. Just use of those and you should be good.

In Europe `DE89370400440532013000` should do the trick (that one is German).

Comment: Thanks Henry! That worked. I wonder why Stripe has no searchable error repository, so I had to go to stack overflow.